# PHP / JS - Leader board for game

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, wordpress, html

I'm creating a leader board (a small results table) for a Javascript game i've created which displays the top three 3 scores, the score will be a string e.g - '100'.

How would i insert/retrieve the score data into and from my DB? the game sits in a wordpress site, are there wordpress php functions that would help me insert/query this data.

thanks in advance, Cam

Comment: I see that you have seemed to go the ajax route with your project by looking at your next question. Why have you not selected my answer as the correct one?

Comment: Thanks for help btw, it got me on track

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ajax would be the way to do this you can create a simple php file that you can set the high scores from when the game ends and retrieve them also with another one.

more on jquery ajax http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

an example of php with jquery ajax http://www.php4every1.com/tutorials/jquery-ajax-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

An easier solution would be to use Clay.io - we've spent a lot of time working on our API, of which leaderboards is a feature.

Have a look at the [Developer Info](http://clay.io/devlanding) page, and [docs for HTML5 leaderboards](http://clay.io/docs/leaderboards).

The code ends up being as simple as: `( new Clay.Leaderboard( { id: 1 } ) ).show();`

Disclaimer: I am a co-founder of Clay.io

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is required that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.

Comment: Just now saw this - added in the disclaimer :)